# Cannot receive email from PHP mail()

Tags: php, ajax, email

I am trying to make a contact form where a user can fill in the details and it will be sent to my email address. The PHP script says it is sent but when I check my email there is no mail. I am also trying to implement this using AJAX. This is my code

```
                        $('#submit').click(function () {
                                    var name = $('#name').val();
                                    var email = $('#email').val();
                                    var message = $('#message').val();

                                    $.ajax({
                                        type: 'POST',
                                        url: 'send.php?name=' + name,
                                        data: 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&message=' + message,
                                        success: function (result) {
                                         //   $('#submit_wrp').load(location.href + ' #submit');
                                                $("#result").html(result);
                                           // $('#submit').val("Invited");
                                           // alert(name + " "  + email);

                                        },
                                        error: function (result) {
                                            alert("error" + name);
                                                $("#result").html(result);
                                        }
                                    });
                                });
```

This is the PHP code

```
$Rname = $_POST['name'];
$meesg = $_POST['message'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$to = "example@gmail.com";
$subject = "Review";
$message = $meesg;
$headers = "From:" + $Rname + $email;
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

  if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
    echo "Mail was sent and has done its job.";
} else {
    echo "Error, check your logs.";
}
```

Please help!!!!

Comment: Is this your local host or live server on which you are running a script ?

Comment: Did you check in your spam mails?

Comment: `$headers = "From:" + $Rname + $email;` should be `$headers = "From:" . $Rname . $email;`

Comment: Yes, but there are no mails

Comment: your hosting account has smtp service ?

Comment: @devpro I tried that, still does not work

Comment: I am using 000webhost

Comment: am I going to get shot down for telling the OP to check for errors, look at their console and possibly include the **missing** HTML form for this? *lol*

Comment: 000webhost blocks almost every PHP function due to spam, hackers, attackers and other security reasons.

Comment: I suggest you to switch from 000webhost to hostinger. Just download the backup of your server files (along with database) and upload it back at hostinger.

Comment: 000webhost has their own support forum which are probably better equipped to answer questions regarding their limitations.

Comment: FYI, you're sending 'name' twice; once in the url, and once in the data. Remove from the URL. Plus, you're firing the mail() function twice. Remove just below the $headers declaration, but keep the next one.

Answer (score 0):

hardcode your values then check again.

```
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

if there is problem then check your smtp settings on server.

Comment: *"if there is problem then check your smtp settings on server."* - Thing is, that awful server they're on, doesn't offer SMTP to free accounts; *fact, not fiction*.

Comment: this link may helps  [link](http://www.000webhost.com/forum/web-programming/23998-php-mail-function.html)

Comment: @MJunaidAslam This link is very old. 000webhost has blocked the mail() function for so far I know this is because people made email bombs with it to spam other users e-mail accounts.

Comment: I have output m variables and it prints it out. I checked on the SMTP settings. SMTP is localhost

Answer (score 0):

Did you search for the mail php possibilities at the forum of you hosting company?
Try to look at the sendmail_path:

```
<?php
   phpinfo();  
?>
```

Maybe it is not configured properly.

Further maybe you need more headers to sent with your email to prevent filtering to the spambox.

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: frommail@gmail.com" . "\r\n" ."Reply-To: tomail@gmail.com". "\r\n" ."X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
```

Comment: There is no need to use 'print' here. Simply including the phpinfo() function will output what you need.

Comment: I don't understand, what should I do with the phpinfo() function?

Comment: Just remove 'print' and you're done: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` Voila! @Likitha - this was a comment on the post by @J. Hofste

Comment: Note that with or without `print` the `phpinfo()` will be executed anyways.

Comment: with phpinfo() you can view your webserver configurations easily!

Comment: I get this sendmail_from no value no value
sendmail_path /usr/local/bin/phpsendmail /usr/local/bin/phpsendmail
serialize_precision 100 100
short_open_tag On On
SMTP localhost localhost
smtp_port 25

Comment: I have even tried this, but there were no errors error_reporting(E_ALL);
      ini_set('display_errors', 1);